# Unable to bind data to webgrid in a partial view

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am calling a method in my controller to save some data to the database
and when done returns all the data in that table. This works well as 
am able to return the data when i step through this method.

I am having problems binding the data returned to my partial view.

I got this error message which is just unrelated to what am doing

Any Ideas of what am doing wrong?

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'kronoshours' of non-nullable type 'System.Decimal' 
>       for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult EmployeeHoursDetail(System.String, System.String, System.Decimal, System.String, 
>       System.String, System.DateTime, System.String, System.String)' in 'Papa.Main.Controllers.HomeController'. 
>       An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
>       Parameter name: parameters

Here is the section that should hold  the partial view data

```
<div id="mainListContent">
    @{ Html.RenderPartial("_Taskdisplay", Model.DisplayTaskData);}
</div>
```

Here is the get i am doing

```
var url = "@Url.Action("WriteEmployeeTaskToDb", "Home")";
var CompleteData = JSON.stringify({ 'EmployeeTask': objdata });

$.get(url, { 'itemstowrite': CompleteData }, function (result) {
   // console.log(result);
   $('#mainListContent').html(result);
```

Here is the controller method

```
public ActionResult WriteEmployeeTaskToDb(string itemstowrite)
{
    Employeehourstaskinfo getAllTaskSaved = new Employeehourstaskinfo();
    try
    {
        var stripOffObjectName = JObject.Parse(itemstowrite)["EmployeeTask"];
        var cleanedData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Employeetaskdto>(stripOffObjectName.ToString());
        getAllTaskSaved.DisplayEmphoursTask = _edmDataService.WriteTaskToDb(cleanedData, "Add");
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
    return PartialView("_Taskdisplay", getAllTaskSaved);
}
```

Here is a model

```
public class Employeehourstaskinfo
{
    public List<Employeehourstask> DisplayEmphoursTask { get; set; }
}
```

Here is another model

```
public class Employeehourstask
{
    public Int64 Id { get; set; }
    public string Task { get; set; }
    public decimal? Hours { get; set; }
    public decimal? Piececount { get; set; }
}
```

Attached is the method. I don't know why it is going back to this method.

```
public ActionResult EmployeeHoursDetail(string employee, string department, decimal kronoshours, string uniqueId, string empId, DateTime strDate, string strbrn, string strdepn)
{
    Employeehoursdetails getEmhourdetails = null;
    try
    {
        getEmhourdetails = _edmDataService.GetEmployeeHoursDetails(employee, department, kronoshours, uniqueId, empId, strDate, strbrn,strdepn);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {           
        throw;
    }
    return View(getEmhourdetails);
}
```

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Comment: The error related to passing incorrect parameters to your `EmployeeHoursDetail()` method - you have not even shown that method or where you call it from

Comment: Thank you Stephen. I added the method you requested for. I don't know why it is going back to another method.

Comment: Somewhere you have code that is calling that method (and have not provided a value for the parameter `kronoshours`)

Comment: Ok. I will check it again.